# RTOS MicroC tasking

Tags: c, rtos, ucos, microc

I've been working on some RTOS MicroC project and whenever I've implemented some function it works just fine outside the task, but whenever I put in the task it just wouldn't do anything. I know I might not get answer to this, but any tips where to start looking would be a big help, thanks in advance.

```
a_sem = OSSemCreate(1);

static void AppTask1(void *p_arg)
{
    (void) p_arg;
    INT8U perr;
    while (1)
    {
        OSSemPend(a_sem, 0, &perr);
        planeAngles();// Functon that works outside the task
        OSSemPost(a_sem);
        OSTimeDly(OS_TICKS_PER_SEC/20);
    }
}

static void AppTask2(void *p_arg)
{
    (void) p_arg;
    INT8U perr;
    while (1)
    {
        OSSemPend(a_sem, 0, &perr);
        servoTurns(); // Functon that works outside the task
        OSSemPost(a_sem);
        OSTimeDly(OS_TICKS_PER_SEC/20);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both tasks wait on a semaphore, but it is not clear where that semaphore is *initially* given.  It seems likely that neither task ever returns from the `OSSemPend` call.

Comment: What do you mean by that "where that semaphore is initially given"?

Comment: I mean the code fragment does not include code that sets the semaphore initially to allow the pend to exit on the first time it is exited.

Comment: I guess you mean this:a_sem = OSSemCreate(1);

Comment: @CookieDemon : Yes! So update the question to include the necessary information.  The fact that both answers so far have picked up on the possibility that this is not done should tell you that the question is deficient if in fact you have done that.  The point is that it is almost certainly not that these functions do nothing, but rather than they are not called at all - your debugger will tel you that by placing a breakpoint on these calls.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code, before `AppTask1` and `AppTask2` are created, you should have a line of code like this:

```
OSSemCreate(a_sem, 1, &perr);
```

You are creating a semaphore, `a_sem` with an initial value of `1` so that the first task that calls `OSSemPend` will successfully acquire the semaphore.

Also, you should not block forever on `OSSemPend`.  Wait for awhile and then check the error status:

```
OSSemPend(a_sem, 10, &perr);
if(perr == OS_ERR_NONE)
{
    /* You have the semaphore */
}
else
{
    /* Error! Maybe a timeout */
}
```

Comment: I do have it:   a_sem = OSSemCreate(1);

Comment: @CookieDemon You are expecting us to read minds. That code needs to be included in the question to avoid us wasting our time!

Comment: Different versions of MicroC do it differently, I guess.